# MOODLE Complete install package for windows - how to start over?

Tags: php, installation, moodle

I installed the complete package, set up the db password etc... It all installed successfully... But when I went to log into the site... I was unable to... I couldn't retrieve my password either... So what I did... I deleted the moodle directory from my computer and downloaded it again... in hope that I would be able to install it all again... However, I haven't had any luck

I am getting this in the command prompt:

CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Cannot find php.exe
Must abort these process!
Note: if you're running Moodle.exe from command shell, it must be run from its d
irectory.
Press any key to continue . . .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting the cmd.exe - is this in a browser?

If you can't login after a fresh install, then have a look through this checklist: https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Installation_FAQ#I_can.27t_log_in_-_I_just_stay_stuck_on_the_login_screen

You can also change the password in the database. If you are using mysql then you can use:

```
UPDATE mdl_user
SET password = md5('yournewpassword')
WHERE username = 'admin'
```

Comment: Thank you for that. When I double click on Start Moodle in my install directory it brings up the cmd.exe

Comment: Ah right, you've downloaded an install package for windows? My advice would be to install manually using xampp - https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Windows_installation_using_XAMPP

Comment: Is there a way around it without having to install manually? I just want to play with the themes... @russel-england